# Comma separator problem of custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I want to add a new custom taxonomy name as "1 bedroom,2 bathrooms,4 kithenrooms" .

[image]

It's working well from "add new category panel" but not work on "Add new post" type panel. One name is breakdown into 3 names

Comment: It's not exactly what you are asking, but from perspective of WordPress data storage it would make sense to store such quantifiable data in custom fields.

Answer (score 1):

Commas in the post page tags areas means different words, so wordpress will see `1 bedroom,2 bathrooms,4 kithenrooms` as three separate words namely, `1 bedroom` , `2 bathrooms` and `4 kithenrooms`.

Create your tags to look like this `1 bedroom-2 bathrooms-4 kithenrooms` or`1 bedroom 2 bathrooms 4 kithenrooms`

Comment: If my answer was helpfull, please mark it as accepted.